# Podspec correct search paths organization

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I have a project that I want to be a part of cocoapods or just have an easy installation via cocoapods.

Ok, let's see in it.

It has directories in root:

`Tools/ #directory where all items of project stored`

`ExternalLibraries/ # directory where all external libraries stored (.a libraries of third party guys with their .h header files)`

`Submodules/ # directory where all external projects stored that have open source code and can be placed as submodule`

`Example/ # directory with example`

Ok, which options I should specify in Podspec file for correct behaviour?

I ended up with this spec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "WowProjectTools"

  s.source       = {
    :git => "https://github.com/wow/WowProjectTools.git",
    :submodules => true
  }

  s.source_files  = "Tools/**/*.{h,m}" # include all tools files
  s.exclude_files = "Example" # exclude all examples

  s.frameworks = "Foundation", "SystemConfiguration", "CoreData" # add all frameworks (system frameworks)

  s.libraries = "icucore", "z" # ok, I need these libraries like libz.dylib and libicucore.dylib
  s.vendored_libraries = 'ExternalLibraries/**' # hmm, these libraries are third party, no?

  s.requires_arc = true #
  s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => ["./Submodules/**/*.h","./ExternalLibraries/**/*.h"] } # add header search paths

end
```